# Does waiter still applied as male server?

Tags: meaning-in-context, ambiguity, context

I am not native English speaker.

Want to ask, does 'Waiter' still applied to male specific gender of 'Server'?
Or could we call female server as Waiter too?

The thing is I am currently developing a mobile client application for Waiter/Waitress ordering application. So I need to give it a name.

I know the word Server is now used in most of restaurant nowadays.
But if I use Server as part of my application name, it will be ambiguous. As in IT world, Server means device (hardware) that provides functionality for other client program. So I am avoiding using Server as part of my application name.

So, is it okay if use Waiter as part of my application name?

Comment: What about "[wait staff](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/waitstaff)"?

Comment: Or in the UK, "waiting staff"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what kind of restaurant you're in, a 'Waiter' and a 'Server' can be different. In most middling restaurants, they are, indeed, the same though.
A waiter is generally someone who 'waits' on your table. Takes your order, makes sure you're being properly hosted and so on. A server solely serves the food and tends to the dishes.

To answer your question, yes, 'waiter' is generally applied solely to male attendants. However, simply using the word 'waiter' in your application wouldn't be wrong. If you decide to provide features in your application, that would imply a female host, you should probably use the word 'waitress' instead.

**Friendly tip: Generally, while naming an application, you might want to employ wordplay and not just go for an obvious name.**

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: So far, it is pretty reasonable answer. And as for the friendly tip, I understood that using wordplay definitely great idea. But I already make some client apps which it's name has solid pattern. "MyBrand" followed by specific work-person that will using it. As simple as that, so that others will easily recognize its funcionality, and interested to use it too.

Answer (score 0):

'Waiter' can be used generically for both male and female, but if differentiating, it would be 'waiter' and 'waitress'.

If though, you are naming an application, why not use something a little more original, like 'Servitor'?

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/servitor

Answer (score 0):

There is a word derived from Waiter/Waitress, which I don't believe to be in common use but which might suit your needs. 
In the 1980s non-gender specific language was becoming more dominant, and before 'server' became the go-to term, the word 'Waitron' was briefly modish. 
[Merriam-Webster gives it a definition of](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/waitron)

> waitperson

in turn defined as

> a waiter or waitress

and further notes:

> The word is probably a blend of "waiter/waitress" and "-tron," a suffix that seems to allude to the machinelike impersonality of waiting tables.

Comment: Sounds like something off Captain Scarlet.